# Javascript 30 second console count down timer

Tags: javascript, function, console, countdowntimer, console.log

I am interested in creating a basic countdown timer in the console of Javascript. My code needs to countdown from 30 and must stop at 0. I have worked through some code but for some reason it is not working. I am a noob at Javascript (First programming language and only been doing 5 weeks). Please help. Below is my code so far.

```
var i = 30;

function startTimer() {

    var countdownTimer = setInterval(function() {

        console.log(i);
        i = i - 1;

        if (i <= 0) {
            clearTimeout(countdownTimer);
        }

    }, 1000);

}

startTimer();
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: _"not working"_ is insufficient.  Explain what you expect and what is actually happening.  Please visit the [help] to learn about basic question guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear *interval*, not timeout since you are using `setInterval` for your timer:

```
var i = 30;

function startTimer() {

    var countdownTimer = setInterval(function() {

        console.log(i);
        i = i - 1;

        if (i <= 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        }

    }, 1000);

}

startTimer();
```

Comment: Thanks very much for answering my question it helped a lot. There is just one problem. The timer goes in the minus's despite the code being fixed. help? Thanks heaps. Edit: Doesn't matter i fixed it THANKS!

Comment: It should not, compare with my code carefully, it should work.